# submit get change into GET

Tags: php, submit

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
```

My form uses `method="post"` and `action="myform.php"` when I submit my form, I use `isset($_POST['submit'])` or `$_REQUEST['submit']` to catch the post and it doesn't work.

```
$x=$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; // I get GET
echo "This is the REQUEST_METHOD=$x<br>";
```

This is the REQUEST_METHOD=GET

```
if(!isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
     echo $_POST["submit"];
     echo "submit is not posted<br>";
}
```

submit is not posted

What else can I check?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An error on my PHP wasn't reported and I try and try by dumping my variables.
Finally using `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, I got `NOTICES` telling me that a variable wasn't supported.

I didn't use `$` to define my variable.
I recreated my form by adding some PHP code until I start having problems. Changed it and now is working.